# Add view to windowManager that respects soft keyboard InputMode="adjustPan"

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-windowmanager

I have added a view to windowManager that stays above window, but when the soft keyboard appears with mode = "adjustPan" (i want to leave it like that), and moves the window up, the added view is not moving with it, how can i force it to move along? Here is my code:

```
private void drawLogoAboveAll() {

        changeActionBarTextMarginLeft((int) PxToDp.convertDpToPixel(36, this));
        mLogo= new ImageView(this);

        mLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.dvor_logo_plain);
        mLogoParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                (int) PxToDp.convertDpToPixel(50, this),
                (int) PxToDp.convertDpToPixel(50, this),
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        mLogoParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
        mLogoParams.x = (int) PxToDp.convertPixelsToDp(10, this);
        mLogoParams.y = (int) PxToDp.convertPixelsToDp(20, this);
        windowManager.addView(mLogo, mLogoParams);
        mDvorLogo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onOptionsItemSelected(homeItem);
            }
        });

    }
```